# Xpath with contains() in importXML()

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I've done dozens times, but now don't get what I'm doing wrong. I want to extract specific records, into 2 separate columns (I know that order wil not match), so I use:

```
//a/@href[contains(.; "github")]
```

and

```
//*[contains(text(); "Pricing:")]
```

But non of them is working - where my mistake? 
(my sandbox: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11Z3xybq_eYQvjn2-UBOomgeJxFrrsFoXKzF9yZSeASM/edit#gid=1841586203 with LT localle)

Comment: Your code is password protected :-/

Comment: Sorry, now open, but found problem myself, appreciate for reaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

damn, those google sheet localles!!!... must be:

```
//a/@href[contains(., "github")]
```

and

```
//*[contains(text(), "Pricing:")]
```

I'll keep for further reference.